# Python MySQL-Connector taking more than a minute to open a connection

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda, mysql-python

MySQL-Connector for python is taking > 1 minute to open a connection to the Database.

I'm writing an AWS Lambda function to simply pull the current secret from AWS Secret manager and then use that secret to open a connection to an SQL Database and run a query to fetch some test data.

```
secret = {
        'user': (responseDict['User ID']),
        'password': (responseDict['Password']),
        'host': (responseDict['Data Source']),
        'database': (responseDict['Initial Catalog']),
        'raise_on_warnings': True
}

def connect_database(secret):
    # Creates a client connection to the database, using the secret 
    log.info('Attempting to connect')
    try:
        dbClient = mysql.connector.connect(**secret)

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            logger.error('ERROR: Failed to auth with the SQL Database.')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            logger.error('ERROR: Database does not exist.')
        else:
            logger.error('ERROR: Unkown error when connecting to database')
            logger.error(err)

    logging.info('Connected succesfully')
    return dbClient
```

When I first ran the lambda function, it failed due to reaching the timeout threshold of 3 seconds, so I increased the timeout to 60 seconds and placed a few info logs at various points of the script to find the point where it times out. To my suprise, with a 60-second threshold, it still times out.

The last log shown is the "log.info('Attempting to connect')" just before it tries to open a connection to the SQL Server. The 'Connected Succesfully' does not log and neither does any of the error catches.

Can anyone clarify if the connection should take this long or the more likely choice, point out where I've gone wrong?

**EDIT: This ended up being related to a networking issue that I was unaware of, thanks!**

Comment: AWS Lambda function itself takes sometime to get ready and execute, eventhouh lambda is in hotstand by mode. please consider this fact when you're setting the timeout. Try increasing the timeout, you can increase timeout as 300 seconds and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Lambda function itself takes sometime to get ready and execute, eventhouh lambda is in hotstand by mode. please consider this fact when you're setting the timeout. Try increasing the timeout, you can increase timeout as 300 seconds and try.